# Jetpack Navigation: how to navigate from child of one nested graph to child from another nested graph?

Tags: android, navigation, parent-child, android-architecture-navigation, android-jetpack-navigation

Navigation structure:

```
MainActivity
|- nav_root
   |- HomeFragment
   |- AuthNestedGraph
   |  |- nav_auth
   |  |  |-BeforeOtpFragment(home)
   |  |  |-OtpFragment
   |
   |- ProfileNestedGraph
   |  |- nav_prfole
   |  |  |-ProfileFragmentOne(home)
   |  |  |-ProfileFragmentTwo
```

[image]
[image]

I can navigate from HomeFragment to BeforeOtp(nav_auth home), toProfileOne(nav_profile home).
Also i can navigate from any auth fragment to toProfileOne, or from profile fragments to BeforeOtp by global id

But how navigate to child fragment that is not set home from fragment at another nested graph/nav file? Like to OtpFragment/ProfileTwoFragment. How to change navcontroller?

When trying global i got an exception: "cannot be found from the current destination Destination"

I can do it by deeplinks but it is not solution im looking for.

[This project github](https://github.com/veygard/JetpackChildNav)

[image]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Turned out that answer was pretty simple, but hope it can help someone.

So, we want navigate from any Auth fragment from nav_auth to ProfileTwo from nav_profile.
What we do:

1. Add global action to Profile Two in nav_profile:
   [image]

```
    <action
    android:id="@+id/action_global_profileTwoFragment"
    app:destination="@id/profileTwoFragment"
    app:popUpTo="@id/profileTwoFragment"
    app:popUpToInclusive="true"
    app:launchSingleTop="false" />
```

2. In navigate function we find navController. Set new Graph by id of navigation file, where is the needed fragment located. And navigate by global action:

```
    override fun routeToProfileTwoFragment() {
        val navController = fragment.findNavController()
        navController.setGraph(R.navigation.nav_profile)
        navController.navigate(R.id.action_global_profileTwoFragment)
    }
```

3. Becouse graph was changed if we want navigate to main navigation graph(nav_root) we need changed it back when navigate(also add global action to home fragment):

```
    override fun routeMain() {
        val navController = fragment.findNavController()
        navController.setGraph(R.navigation.nav_root)
        navController.navigate(R.id.action_global_home)
    }
```

[Github project was updated](https://github.com/veygard/JetpackChildNav)

[image]

Comment: why we should change the grapgh while all are in the same graph as nested graphs? isn't it enough to be in the same file? it's useless now including the tag, am I right?

Comment: When we change the graph for navigating to the global action, the bottom navigation view items do not work anymore. How to manage the same situation with the bottom navigation menu?

Comment: @MUmer, hey, when navigate by bottom navigation u can try to change graph back to root nav file:


```fun changeGraphToRoot(fragment: Fragment):NavController {
    val navController = fragment.findNavController()
    navController.setGraph(R.navigation.nav_root)
    return  navController
}
```
And use it like this:
```changeGraphToRoot(fragment).navigate(R.id.action_global_to_chat_nav)```