# Android Navigation - how to go two destinations deep?

Tags: android, navigation, navigation-drawer, android-navigation-graph

I have an app that manages `Boxes`.
This app has [a single activity](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2k8x8V77CrU) and uses fragments as destinations.
It has (among others) the following destinations/fragments:

- `Home` (registered as topLevelDestination)
- `BoxesManagement` (registered as topLevelDestination)
- `BoxEdit`

From the home destination I want to offer a convenient link to create a new box.
For that I want to link `BoxEdit` directly, but with `BoxesManagement` in the back stack.

## Attempt 1 - Explicit Deep Linking

Since an intermediate destination will only land on the back stack when it is the [start destination of a `<navigation>` element](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-deep-link#explicit), I placed `BoxesManagement` (as start) and `BoxEdit` in a nested graph.
The nested graph is in a separate file, but `<include>`d in the parent graph.
Then I used:

```
findNavController()
    .createDeepLink()
    .setDestination(R.id.nav_edit_box)
    .createPendingIntent()
    .send()
```

This did work in the way that it got me to the desired destination with `BoxesManagement` in the back stack.
However, it causes two issues:

- The application is started again. At least that is what I assume happens, since the entire screen flashes very briefly. This behavior lets me assume that I am not supposed to be using deep links for in-app navigation. (This is not surprising as the documentation never hints at this use-case.)
- When I go back to `BoxesManagement`, I see the hamburger menu icon (as expected). But when I use the drawer menu to navigate to `Home`, nothing happens.

## Attempt 2 - Direct Navigation

```
findNavController()
    .navigate(R.id.nav_box_edit)
```

This does not work and simply fails with:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Navigation action/destination <APP-PKG>:id/nav_box_edit cannot be found from the current destination Destination(<APP-PKG>:id/nav_home) label=Home class=<APP-PKG>.ui.HomeFragment
```

I am not surprised, as [Murat Yener from Google](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/navigation-nested-graphs-and-include-tag-92fd62739b73) already pointed out that this is not supported.

### Attempt 2b - Setting the Graph

From [this question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69161846/jetpack-navigation-how-to-navigate-from-child-of-one-nested-graph-to-child-from) I got the idea to set the graph on the nav controller before navigating.

```
findNavController().apply {
    setGraph(R.navigation.nav_graph_boxes)
    navigate(R.id.nav_box_edit)
}
```

This does work, but also causes two issues:

- When following this navigation, the nav-controller's graph is now `R.navigation.nav_graph_boxes` instead of `R.navigation.nav_graph`. When I use a different path with single steps through `BoxesManagement`, I can also reach `BoxEdit` but with `R.navigation.nav_graph` as the controller's graph.
- The same issue as above with deep linking, navigating to `Home` using the drawer menu does nothing. I believe this is actually a direct consequence of the first issue.

The proposed solution in the linked Q&A is to set the graph back to `R.navigation.nav_graph` when navigating back.
I don't know where in the code to do that though, as I don't navigate back through any explicit action, but rather through the *up*-button and the drawer menu, which - as stated before - does not work anymore with this approach.

## Attempt 3 - Implicit Deep Linking

As suggested by the [official doc](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-navigate#uri) I decided to try implicit deep linking, even though that brings none of that sweet type-safety that I was promised when using the navigation component.

I added

```xml
<deepLink app:uri="android-app://my.app.url/boxes/{boxId}/edit"/>
```

to the `nav_box_edit` fragment definition and used

```
findNavController()
    .navigate(Uri.parse("android-app://my.app.url/boxes/0/edit"))
```

from the `Home` destination.

This got me to my destination, but again I have a problem with this:

- It does not put `BoxesManagement` into the back stack (this is to be expected per the documentation).

## Question

How do I properly navigate to a (nested) destination while putting another destination on the back stack before it?

Comment: If you want to add two destinations to the back stack, why don't you call `navigate()` twice?

Comment: At first I thought this wouldn't work (see my answer below), but I figured it out. Maybe add a sentence or two about that to the documentation? In my mind `navigate()` meant: "Go here, now! Don't do anything else" I wrongly assumed that execution would just continue with the lifecycle of the target destination.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Navigating two Destinations Deep

In order to create a back stack as desired, you just have to push all desired destinations on the stack:

```
findNavController().apply {
    navigate(R.id.nav_boxes_management)
    navigate(R.id.nav_box_edit)
}
```

This works only if all destinations are in the same nav graph. As specified in the question, this is not the case here, so a slightly different approach needs to be taken:

```
findNavController().apply {
    navigate(FragmentHomeDirections.actionBoxesManagement())
    navigate(FragmentBoxesManagementDirections.actionEditBox(0L))
}
```

Using the directions of the now-top-of-the-stack destination `BoxesManagement`, the navigation into the nested graph succeeds.

(Thanks to [ianhanniballake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73652899/android-navigation-how-to-go-two-destinations-deep#comment130063501_73652899) for giving me the crucial hint!)

## Navigating back to `Home`

This works, but I don't know why:

```
findNavController().apply {
    navigate(FragmentHomeDirections.actionBoxesManagement(), navOptions {
        popUpTo(R.id.nav_home) {
            inclusive = false
            saveState = true
        }
    })
    navigate(FragmentBoxesManagementDirections.actionEditBox(0L))
}
```

I figured it out by looking at the source code of `NavigationUI`, which effectively handles the drawer menu actions.

Comment: When you say same nav_graph does it imply same navigation path, or same graph file? because I have some nested graphs but they are all part of the same path through directions.

Comment: By "same nav_graph" I mean the same graph file. If that is not the case, the first code snippet won't work, but the second will.

Comment: Well it actually worked with nested graphs.