# "Deep-link" to a fragment while using the app - Navigation Component

Tags: android, android-architecture-navigation, fragment-backstack, android-deep-link

Suppose for simplicity that an App consists of 3 screens (Home, Account, Payments) and these are hosted inside a Navigation Graph.
When pressing a button in Home screen, user navigates to Account screen.
When pressing a button in Account screen, user navigates to Payments screen.
Is there a way to navigate from Home directly to Payments screen, but also add in the back-stack the Account screen? So that when user navigates back from Payments screen, to see Account screen.
From what I see in the docs a deep-link is not suitable for this use-case.

Comment: This seems to be a possible answer
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73652899/android-navigation-how-to-go-two-destinations-deep#comment130063501_73652899